Given variable A and B containing data of lemma sentiments, what is the correct term for the variable containing average of var A and var B?
I have a data visualization, showing the sentiment of two lemmas "гей" (var a) and "трансгендер" (var b) in a news corpus throughout the year.
Here is the dataframe sample of my data:
  orientasi    tahun sentimen
  <chr>        <int>    <dbl>
1  гей          1991    1.7  
2  гей          1993    3.3  
3  гей          1995   -0.8  
4  гей          1996    1.58 
5  гей          1997    0.606
6  гей          1998    1.8
...  
36 трансгендер  2016   -1.97 
37 трансгендер  2017   -1.98 
38 трансгендер  2018   -0.73 
39 трансгендер  2019   -0.63 
40 трансгендер  2020   -0.982
41 трансгендер  2021    0   

Reproducible code for the dataframe in R:
df <- structure(list(orientasi = c("гей", "гей", "гей", "гей", 
"гей", "гей", "гей", "гей", "гей", "гей", "гей", 
"гей", "гей", "гей", "гей", "гей", "гей", "гей", 
"гей", "гей", "гей", "гей", "гей", "гей", "гей", 
"гей", "гей", "гей", "трансгендер", "трансгендер", 
"трансгендер", "трансгендер", "трансгендер", 
"трансгендер", "трансгендер", "трансгендер", 
"трансгендер", "трансгендер", "трансгендер", 
"трансгендер", "трансгендер"), tahun = c(1991L, 
1993L, 1995L, 1996L, 1997L, 1998L, 1999L, 2000L, 2001L, 2002L, 
2003L, 2004L, 2005L, 2006L, 2007L, 2008L, 2009L, 2010L, 2011L, 
2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 
2007L, 2008L, 2011L, 2012L, 2013L, 2014L, 2015L, 2016L, 2017L, 
2018L, 2019L, 2020L, 2021L), sentimen = c(1.7, 3.3, -0.8, 1.57777777777778, 
0.605555555555556, 1.8, 0.836363636363637, 0.708955223880597, 
0.682666666666666, 0.56875, -0.744354838709678, 0.292857142857143, 
-0.36625, -0.273484848484848, 0.221608040201005, 0.17319587628866, 
-0.0928571428571431, 0.178169014084507, 0.00859374999999992, 
-0.48110599078341, -0.738417266187049, -1.14406779661017, -0.665037593984962, 
-0.424671052631579, -1.50236686390533, -0.525233644859813, -1.03368794326241, 
-0.536619718309859, 2.76666666666667, -1.65, 2.76666666666667, 
0.10625, -0.919047619047619, -2.94137931034483, -0.842528735632184, 
-1.96549295774648, -1.98392857142857, -0.73, -0.63, -0.982191780821917, 
0)), class = c("grouped_df", "tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, 
-41L), groups = structure(list(orientasi = c("гей", "трансгендер"
), .rows = structure(list(1:28, 29:41), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
"vctrs_vctr", "list"))), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"
), row.names = c(NA, -2L), .drop = TRUE))

And here is the data visualization of it

Now I want to show the sentiment for both variables, or in other words, the "average" values for both variables (var c). Currently I define the var c as average of var a and var b. Here is sample of dataframe for var c:
  tahun sentimen orientasi
  <int>    <dbl> <chr>    
1  1991    1.7   avg      
2  1993    3.3   avg      
3  1995   -0.8   avg      
4  1996    1.58  avg      
5  1997    0.606 avg      
6  1998    1.8   avg  

Reproducible code to make the dataframe:
#avg of гей and трансгендер
df_avg <- df %>% 
  group_by(tahun) %>% 
  summarise(sentimen = mean(score)) %>%
  mutate(orientasi = "avg")

And after that, I bind the df and df_avg so that I can visualize both the var a, var b, var c. This is the code I used:
#bind df and df_avg
df_2 <- rbind(df, df_avg)

This is the visualization of df_2, containing var a, var b, and var c:

My question seems to look trivial, but is "average" a suitable term for var c? Another alternative I think of is "гей and трансгендер" but I have the feeling that it might confuse people. Any suggestion of name I should use for var c?

Why not "Average of гей and трансгендер"? However, one thing that you may want to clarify for your audience is if гей and трансгендер have the same weight when calculating the average, i.e. if this is a weighted or unweighted average. For example, if гей occurs just 10 times in 2017, and трансгендер occurs 10,000 times, a reader might wonder if it makes sense to take their unweighted average sentiment score. You may already have thought about that, but I think it's worth clarifying for your audience. Note that you could show both weighted and unweighted averages on the graph.

In addition, you could combine the different plots into a single one, and differentiate the lines with colors or symbols, it would make comparisons much easier. See the section "Plots with multiple lines" on this page for a simple example.
